# The last readable newspaper, book and PDA in Deus Ex

Tags: deus-ex

Deus Ex contains books, newspapers and PDA datacubes that you can read to know more about the world.

After a point, they are becoming less common. The last newspaper that I could ever find in the game before the ending was deeply in the bunkers of MJ12 Ocean Lab. It was about the total collapse (not about "The Collapse", that was one of the endings), and most certainly, last book can be found around this place (I think it must be the 24th chapter of the fictional book "Jacob's Shadow").

But all these are just suggestions. Which is the actual last

- book
- newspaper
- and PDA datacube

can be found in Deus Ex?

Comment: [Here is a list of all books/newspapers/magazines](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Deus_Ex:_Human_Revolution_books,_magazines_and_newspapers).  Similarly, [here is a list of unique e-books](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Doctorate#eBook_Locations).  As far as the last one, I'm not sure how the game works so it might progress the story as you find the items rather than the last one in a playthrough always containing the end of the story.

Comment: I've seen that list but that's only the texts they write, and don't tell which where can be found.

Comment: Those links are for human revolution aren't they?  Wouldn't [deus-ex-human-revolution] be the appropriate tag there as opposed to the original Deus Ex game?

Comment: @Glenn1234 first link is about both (I think), but eBooks were only in HR. Datacubes (that I mentioned in the question) were only in the first game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esoteric question to be sure.  Took a little research...at least from my standpoint.

Last book is in Area 51 Level 3

Last newspaper (I believe) is the one you referenced (unless there's one in the Area 51 Level 2 somewhere?).

Last datacube is a bit questionable since they're scattered all over Area 51 Level 4.

Comment: About data cubes, Area 51 Level 4 is accurate enough for me. =) about newspapers: I've visited the Area 51 Level 2 private barracks/sleeping quarters there's no newspapers there. I couldn't find any of them in Area 51 actually.

Yeah, maybe _can I find any newspaper in Area 51 in Deus Ex?_ would have been a better question.

Comment: @ZoltanSchmidt I checked Area51 Level 2 after I wrote that and didn't find any.  I would say no there are no newspapers.